# Эффективно извлечь значения из HashMap в List

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Какой способ более быстрый и эффективный для получения всех значений из `HashMap` в `List`?

1. С помощью метода `map.values()`
2. С помощью `stream().collect()`
3. С помощью `iterator()`

Comment: К слову, у первого варианта рейтинг 1284 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026736/7485582

Answer (score 2):

**Проведем эксперимент:** возьмем мапу `HashMap<String, String>` из 10 млн различных строк и замерим скорость выполнения методов получения листа из этой мапы.

**Коротко о результатах:** в большинстве случаев разница не велика (время в миллисекундах)

```
// Preparing map.. 23257
// 1 constructor new ArrayList<>()  | 1267
// 2 ArrayList.addAll()             | 1313
// 3 iterator                       | 1195
// 4 enhanced 'for' loop (iterator) | 1194
// 5 stream().collect()             | 1342
// 6 stream().forEach()             | 1411
// 7 parallelStream().collect()     |  494
// 8 parallelStream().forEach()     | 5711
```

Первые два метода: конструктор класса `ArrayList` и метод из него же `addAll` работают примерно одинаково, т.к. оба внутри используют нативный метод `System.arraycopy`. То же самое с методом `iterator` и циклом `for`, который при компиляции в байт-код превращается в тот же `iterator`.

Со стримами другая история: метод `forEach` работает медленнее всего, особенно в параллельном варианте, оптимизация получается в обратную сторону - такой код лучше не писать, а вот метод `collect` очень хорошо отрабатывает в параллельном режиме.

---

**Лучший показатель:** `parallelStream().collect()`

```
map.entrySet().parallelStream().collect(ArrayList::new,
        (list, element) -> list.add(element.getValue()), ArrayList::addAll);
```

Можно упростить чуть-чуть эту строку:

```
map.values().parallelStream()
        .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

И еще чуть-чуть (работает одинаково):

```
map.values().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Подробнее:**

Сперва подготавливаем мапу, заполняем различными значениями `UUID`:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> prepareMap(int capacity) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.print("Preparing map.. ");

    long counter = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (map.size() < capacity) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        map.put(uuid, uuid);
    }
    counter = System.currentTimeMillis() - counter;

    System.out.println(counter);

    System.gc();

    return map;
}
```

Для замера производительности каждого метода будем выполнять по 20 итераций и считать средний показатель:

```
private static void benchmark(String text, int iterations, Runnable runnable) {
    long counter;
    long avgCounter = 0;

    text = optimizeTextLength(text);

    System.out.print(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        counter = System.currentTimeMillis();

        runnable.run();

        counter = System.currentTimeMillis() - counter;
        System.out.print(" | " + counter);
        avgCounter += counter;

        System.gc();
    }
    System.out.println(" || " + avgCounter / iterations);
}

private static String optimizeTextLength(String text) {
    int textLength = 32;
    if (text == null) {
        text = "";
    }
    if (text.length() < textLength) {
        text += " ".repeat(textLength - text.length());
    } else {
        text = text.substring(0, textLength);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Запускаем тест:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int capacity = 10000000;
    int iterations = 20;

    HashMap<String, String> map = prepareMap(capacity);

    benchmark("1 constructor new ArrayList<>()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
    });

    benchmark("2 ArrayList.addAll()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
        arrayList.addAll(map.values());
    });

    benchmark("3 iterator", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            arrayList.add(iterator.next().getValue());
        }
    });

    benchmark("4 enhanced 'for' loop (iterator)", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            arrayList.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    });

    benchmark("5 stream().collect()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(ArrayList::new,
                        (list, element) -> list.add(element.getValue()),
                        ArrayList::addAll);
    });

    benchmark("6 stream().forEach()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(capacity);
        map.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach((element) -> arrayList.add(element.getValue()));
    });

    benchmark("7 parallelStream().collect()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList = map.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .collect(ArrayList::new,
                        (list, element) -> list.add(element.getValue()),
                        ArrayList::addAll);
    });

    benchmark("8 parallelStream().forEach()", iterations, () -> {
        var arrayList =
                Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>(capacity));
        map.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach((element) -> {
            arrayList.add(element.getValue());
        });
    });

//  // Этот код очень долго работает
//  benchmark("9 parallelStream().forEach()", iterations, () -> {
//      List<String> arrayList =
//              new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(capacity));
//      map.entrySet().parallelStream()
//              .forEach((element) -> arrayList.add(element.getValue()));
//  });
}
```

Полный вывод (время в миллисекундах):

```
// Preparing map.. 23257
// 1 constructor new ArrayList<>()  | 1317 | 1297 | 1282 | 1259 | 1242 | 1249 | 1246 | 1237 | 1242 | 1241 | 1277 | 1271 | 1254 | 1283 | 1310 | 1250 | 1263 | 1268 | 1279 | 1283 || 1267
// 2 ArrayList.addAll()             | 1274 | 1326 | 1326 | 1329 | 1325 | 1282 | 1345 | 1330 | 1321 | 1324 | 1282 | 1280 | 1329 | 1292 | 1324 | 1304 | 1292 | 1330 | 1331 | 1326 || 1313
// 3 iterator                       | 1330 | 1465 | 1170 | 1175 | 1172 | 1179 | 1170 | 1179 | 1180 | 1177 | 1172 | 1175 | 1162 | 1172 | 1166 | 1173 | 1171 | 1173 | 1173 | 1177 || 1195
// 4 enhanced 'for' loop (iterator) | 1334 | 1450 | 1173 | 1167 | 1167 | 1168 | 1170 | 1169 | 1163 | 1171 | 1176 | 1162 | 1177 | 1174 | 1171 | 1172 | 1168 | 1193 | 1198 | 1171 || 1194
// 5 stream().collect()             | 1319 | 1310 | 1355 | 1349 | 1341 | 1333 | 1338 | 1352 | 1350 | 1335 | 1334 | 1333 | 1346 | 1358 | 1350 | 1343 | 1346 | 1347 | 1352 | 1349 || 1342
// 6 stream().forEach()             | 1407 | 1422 | 1417 | 1413 | 1450 | 1474 | 1462 | 1388 | 1381 | 1385 | 1397 | 1394 | 1406 | 1393 | 1425 | 1405 | 1428 | 1399 | 1385 | 1389 || 1411
// 7 parallelStream().collect()     |  619 |  512 |  498 |  507 |  484 |  485 |  490 |  517 |  477 |  471 |  479 |  494 |  494 |  470 |  472 |  486 |  482 |  479 |  474 |  507 ||  494
// 8 parallelStream().forEach()     | 5652 | 5832 | 5735 | 5714 | 5821 | 5984 | 5742 | 5596 | 6017 | 5668 | 5665 | 5426 | 5918 | 5508 | 5389 | 5740 | 5488 | 5585 | 5879 | 5875 || 5711
```